# Using search_full_archive in Tweepy

Tags: tweepy

Does anyone know how to use the `search_full_archive` feature in tweepy module? I used the cursor feature similar to the regular search, but it didn't work.

```
import tweepy as tw

api_key = '***'
api_secret_key = '***'
access_token = '***'
access_token_secret = '***'

#Authenticate
auth = tw.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret_key)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
api = tw.API(auth)

# search tweets
def get_tweets_full(hashtag):
    tweetObj_full = tw.Cursor(
        self.api.search_full_archive,
        environment_name = 'VolcanicDisaster', # Dev environment label from twitter developer dashboard
        query = hashtag
    )
     return tweetObj

get_tweets(hashtag = '#kilauea')
```

I get an error stating 'API object has no attribute search_full_archive'. However, if I use the regular search method `api.search` (with its parameters q) instead of `api.search_full_archive` it works fine. I want to look back for tweets from 2 years ago and require api_full_search, wondering if anyone knows how to use this feature?
I have managed set up the premium account (sandbox version - free) with twitter API, but when I input `dir(api)` I don't see the `search_full_archive` method in the output list of methods.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, full archive features only available on Premium/Enterprice API. But you can also upgrade your standart developer account to Premium for FREE in limited.

Secondly, tweepy with version 3.10.0, the **full archive** feature is supported!!! But you need to update tweepy. Currently it is not possible to update with pip so you need to update as `pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy@master`. Then your API will ready to use,

Lastly, with the [documentation of tweepy](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=full#API.search_full_archive) you need to redescribe your API. Here is 2 example of tweepy API object;

```
search_words ='**KEYWORD/HASHTAG/USERNAME**'
date_since = "13-08-2020"
date_since_pro = "202008130000"
numTweets = 100

# standart search
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=search_words, since=date_since).items(numTweets)

# premium search
tweets=tweepy.Cursor(api.search_full_archive,environment_name='**ENV NAME FROM API**', query=search_words, fromDate=date_since_pro).items(numTweets)
```

As you see the need to change date format with **search_full_archive** feature.

Answer (score 0):

Search full archive feature is only available on Premium and Enterprise Api accesses. Free API users can only have access to recent tweets (recent 7 days).

Reference: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/overview

Comment: According to the tweepy documentation, you can use full_access_seach with the premium account, which I have managed to set up (the sandox version - it's free but gives you access to premium with lower tweets per request). So it should work. The only issue is that the method isn't available when I type dir(API)

Comment: You are right. From what I have understood from here: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1175 it is planned for next version of tweepy to support premium search features.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this too. But kinda thought it's already implemented since the post is early 2019, but perhaps its not :(

Comment: So we can't do full archive search?